# How can I loop through array with one same value and group them

Tags: arrays, loops, cakephp, foreach

I have a nested foreach loop that iterates through classes and offerings. In one case, I have a Yoga class with two offerings; Session 1 and Session 2. 
Signing up for a session means attending all dates.

Session 1 has 5 unique dates and Session 2 has 5 unique dates. Currently, my foreach loop shows each as it's own "offering":
Yoga
Session 1
10/1/16
5pm - 6pm

Session 1
10/8/16
3pm - 4pm

Session 1
10/11/16
10am - 11am

Session 1
10/12/16
10am - 11am

Session 1
10/15/16
4pm - 5p

Session 2
11/1/16
5pm - 6pm

Session 2
11/9/16
3pm - 4pm

Session 2
11/15/16
10am - 11am

Session 2
11/16/16
10am - 11am

Session 2
11/23/16
4pm - 5pm

so now I'm running into a problem. Perhaps I need another loop so the 5 unique dates get listed within each Session offering?

**Session 1**

10/1/16
5pm - 6pm

10/8/16
3pm - 4pm

10/11/16
10am - 11am

10/12/16
10am - 11am

10/15/16
4pm - 5pm

**Session 2**

11/1/16
5pm - 6pm

11/9/16
3pm - 4pm

11/15/16
10am - 11am

11/16/16
10am - 11am

11/23/16
4pm - 5pm

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {

if ($row['offering']=="Session 1"){
// do something

}

if ($row['offering']=="Session 2") {
// do something
}

}
```

tried this but it still shows all as individual rows

```
$array = array($row['offering']);
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
   // do stuff
echo $val;
}

}
```

I'm not on the right track...would appreciate some guidance.

A sample var_dump

```
["YOGA"]=> array(10) { 
[0]=> array(20) { ["category"]=> string(7) "Classes" ["course"]=> string(5) "YOGA" ["CourseOfferingID"]=> string(36) "0550AA8D-F437-4578-BD98-95C51D017E62" ["offering"]=> string(15) "YOGA Session 1" ["Semester"]=> string(9) "Fall 2016" ["Days"]=> string(2) "We" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "10/05/2016" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "10/05/2016" ["StartTime"]=> string(7) " 6:00PM" ["EndTime"]=> string(7) "10:00PM" ["Location"]=> string(23) "Off-Site, Quiet Room" ["pricing"]=> NULL ["SIZE"]=> int(10) ["REGISTERED_COUNT"]=> int(1) ["WAITING_LIST_COUNT"]=> int(0) ["ProgramClassificationID"]=> string(36) "AFCAB0B2-24FE-427B-8590-812D74749E6A" ["ProgramClassificationName"]=> string(8) "Wellness" ["SemesterID"]=> string(36) "854E61F8-B564-48F6-AFCD-FAEE597AFF0C" ["CourseID"]=> string(36) "84A92D24-12C3-4487-93C1-4DBFAF2D9A3B" ["RegCloseDate"]=> string(19) "Sep 29 2016 12:00AM" } 

[1]=> array(20) { ["category"]=> string(7) "Classes" ["course"]=> string(5) "YOGA" ["CourseOfferingID"]=> string(36) "0550AA8D-F437-4578-BD98-95C51D017E62" ["offering"]=> string(15) "YOGA Session 1" ["Semester"]=> string(9) "Fall 2016" ["Days"]=> string(2) "Su" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "10/09/2016" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "10/09/2016" ["StartTime"]=> string(7) " 9:00AM" ["EndTime"]=> string(7) " 5:00PM" ["Location"]=> string(8) "Off-Site" ["pricing"]=> NULL ["SIZE"]=> int(10) ["REGISTERED_COUNT"]=> int(1) ["WAITING_LIST_COUNT"]=> int(0) ["ProgramClassificationID"]=> string(36) "AFCAB0B2-24FE-427B-8590-812D74749E6A" ["ProgramClassificationName"]=> string(8) "Wellness" ["SemesterID"]=> string(36) "854E61F8-B564-48F6-AFCD-FAEE597AFF0C" ["CourseID"]=> string(36) "84A92D24-12C3-4487-93C1-4DBFAF2D9A3B" ["RegCloseDate"]=> string(19) "Sep 29 2016 12:00AM" } 

[2]=> array(20) { ["category"]=> string(7) "Classes" ["course"]=> string(5) "YOGA" ["CourseOfferingID"]=> string(36) "0550AA8D-F437-4578-BD98-95C51D017E62" ["offering"]=> string(15) "YOGA Session 1" ["Semester"]=> string(9) "Fall 2016" ["Days"]=> string(2) "We" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "10/12/2016" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "10/12/2016" ["StartTime"]=> string(7) " 6:00PM" ["EndTime"]=> string(7) "10:00PM" ["Location"]=> string(13) "Quiet Room" ["pricing"]=> NULL ["SIZE"]=> int(10) ["REGISTERED_COUNT"]=> int(1) ["WAITING_LIST_COUNT"]=> int(0) ["ProgramClassificationID"]=> string(36) "AFCAB0B2-24FE-427B-8590-812D74749E6A" ["ProgramClassificationName"]=> string(8) "Wellness" ["SemesterID"]=> string(36) "854E61F8-B564-48F6-AFCD-FAEE597AFF0C" ["CourseID"]=> string(36) "84A92D24-12C3-4487-93C1-4DBFAF2D9A3B" ["RegCloseDate"]=> string(19) "Sep 29 2016 12:00AM" } 

[3]=> array(20) { ["category"]=> string(7) "Classes" ["course"]=> string(5) "YOGA" ["CourseOfferingID"]=> string(36) "0550AA8D-F437-4578-BD98-95C51D017E62" ["offering"]=> string(15) "YOGA Session 1" ["Semester"]=> string(9) "Fall 2016" ["Days"]=> string(2) "Sa" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "10/15/2016" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "10/15/2016" ["StartTime"]=> string(7) " 9:00AM" ["EndTime"]=> string(7) " 5:00PM" ["Location"]=> string(11) "YOGA Class" ["pricing"]=> NULL ["SIZE"]=> int(10) ["REGISTERED_COUNT"]=> int(1) ["WAITING_LIST_COUNT"]=> int(0) ["ProgramClassificationID"]=> string(36) "AFCAB0B2-24FE-427B-8590-812D74749E6A" ["ProgramClassificationName"]=> string(8) "Wellness" ["SemesterID"]=> string(36) "854E61F8-B564-48F6-AFCD-FAEE597AFF0C" ["CourseID"]=> string(36) "84A92D24-12C3-4487-93C1-4DBFAF2D9A3B" ["RegCloseDate"]=> string(19) "Sep 29 2016 12:00AM" } 

[4]=> array(20) { ["category"]=> string(7) "Classes" ["course"]=> string(5) "YOGA" ["CourseOfferingID"]=> string(36) "0550AA8D-F437-4578-BD98-95C51D017E62" ["offering"]=> string(15) "YOGA Session 1" ["Semester"]=> string(9) "Fall 2016" ["Days"]=> string(2) "Su" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "10/16/2016" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "10/16/2016" ["StartTime"]=> string(7) " 9:00AM" ["EndTime"]=> string(7) " 5:00PM" ["Location"]=> string(11) "YOGA Class" ["pricing"]=> NULL ["SIZE"]=> int(10) ["REGISTERED_COUNT"]=> int(1) ["WAITING_LIST_COUNT"]=> int(0) ["ProgramClassificationID"]=> string(36) "AFCAB0B2-24FE-427B-8590-812D74749E6A" ["ProgramClassificationName"]=> string(8) "Wellness" ["SemesterID"]=> string(36) "854E61F8-B564-48F6-AFCD-FAEE597AFF0C" ["CourseID"]=> string(36) "84A92D24-12C3-4487-93C1-4DBFAF2D9A3B" ["RegCloseDate"]=> string(19) "Sep 29 2016 12:00AM" } 

[5]=> array(20) { ["category"]=> string(7) "Classes" ["course"]=> string(5) "YOGA" ["CourseOfferingID"]=> string(36) "DE7A6045-2908-47B6-AD13-6DC12FF42F6E" ["offering"]=> string(15) "YOGA Session 2" ["Semester"]=> string(9) "Fall 2016" ["Days"]=> string(2) "Tu" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "11/01/2016" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "11/01/2016" ["StartTime"]=> string(7) " 6:00PM" ["EndTime"]=> string(7) "10:00PM" ["Location"]=> string(23) "Off-Site, Quiet Room" ["pricing"]=> NULL ["SIZE"]=> int(10) ["REGISTERED_COUNT"]=> int(3) ["WAITING_LIST_COUNT"]=> int(0) ["ProgramClassificationID"]=> string(36) "AFCAB0B2-24FE-427B-8590-812D74749E6A" ["ProgramClassificationName"]=> string(8) "Wellness" ["SemesterID"]=> string(36) "854E61F8-B564-48F6-AFCD-FAEE597AFF0C" ["CourseID"]=> string(36) "84A92D24-12C3-4487-93C1-4DBFAF2D9A3B" ["RegCloseDate"]=> string(19) "Oct 26 2016 12:00AM" } 

[6]=> array(20) { ["category"]=> string(7) "Classes" ["course"]=> string(5) "YOGA" ["CourseOfferingID"]=> string(36) "DE7A6045-2908-47B6-AD13-6DC12FF42F6E" ["offering"]=> string(15) "YOGA Session 2" ["Semester"]=> string(9) "Fall 2016" ["Days"]=> string(2) "Su" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "11/06/2016" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "11/06/2016" ["StartTime"]=> string(7) " 9:00AM" ["EndTime"]=> string(7) " 5:00PM" ["Location"]=> string(8) "Off-Site" ["pricing"]=> NULL ["SIZE"]=> int(10) ["REGISTERED_COUNT"]=> int(3) ["WAITING_LIST_COUNT"]=> int(0) ["ProgramClassificationID"]=> string(36) "AFCAB0B2-24FE-427B-8590-812D74749E6A" ["ProgramClassificationName"]=> string(8) "Wellness" ["SemesterID"]=> string(36) "854E61F8-B564-48F6-AFCD-FAEE597AFF0C" ["CourseID"]=> string(36) "84A92D24-12C3-4487-93C1-4DBFAF2D9A3B" ["RegCloseDate"]=> string(19) "Oct 26 2016 12:00AM" } 

[7]=> array(20) { ["category"]=> string(7) "Classes" ["course"]=> string(5) "YOGA" ["CourseOfferingID"]=> string(36) "DE7A6045-2908-47B6-AD13-6DC12FF42F6E" ["offering"]=> string(15) "YOGA Session 2" ["Semester"]=> string(9) "Fall 2016" ["Days"]=> string(2) "Tu" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "11/08/2016" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "11/08/2016" ["StartTime"]=> string(7) " 6:00PM" ["EndTime"]=> string(7) "10:00PM" ["Location"]=> string(13) "Quiet Room" ["pricing"]=> NULL ["SIZE"]=> int(10) ["REGISTERED_COUNT"]=> int(3) ["WAITING_LIST_COUNT"]=> int(0) ["ProgramClassificationID"]=> string(36) "AFCAB0B2-24FE-427B-8590-812D74749E6A" ["ProgramClassificationName"]=> string(8) "Wellness" ["SemesterID"]=> string(36) "854E61F8-B564-48F6-AFCD-FAEE597AFF0C" ["CourseID"]=> string(36) "84A92D24-12C3-4487-93C1-4DBFAF2D9A3B" ["RegCloseDate"]=> string(19) "Oct 26 2016 12:00AM" } 

[8]=> array(20) { ["category"]=> string(7) "Classes" ["course"]=> string(5) "YOGA" ["CourseOfferingID"]=> string(36) "DE7A6045-2908-47B6-AD13-6DC12FF42F6E" ["offering"]=> string(15) "YOGA Session 2" ["Semester"]=> string(9) "Fall 2016" ["Days"]=> string(2) "Sa" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "11/12/2016" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "11/12/2016" ["StartTime"]=> string(7) " 9:00AM" ["EndTime"]=> string(7) " 5:00PM" ["Location"]=> string(11) "YOGA Class" ["pricing"]=> NULL ["SIZE"]=> int(10) ["REGISTERED_COUNT"]=> int(3) ["WAITING_LIST_COUNT"]=> int(0) ["ProgramClassificationID"]=> string(36) "AFCAB0B2-24FE-427B-8590-812D74749E6A" ["ProgramClassificationName"]=> string(8) "Wellness" ["SemesterID"]=> string(36) "854E61F8-B564-48F6-AFCD-FAEE597AFF0C" ["CourseID"]=> string(36) "84A92D24-12C3-4487-93C1-4DBFAF2D9A3B" ["RegCloseDate"]=> string(19) "Oct 26 2016 12:00AM" } 

[9]=> array(20) { ["category"]=> string(7) "Classes" ["course"]=> string(5) "YOGA" ["CourseOfferingID"]=> string(36) "DE7A6045-2908-47B6-AD13-6DC12FF42F6E" ["offering"]=> string(15) "YOGA Session 2" ["Semester"]=> string(9) "Fall 2016" ["Days"]=> string(2) "Su" ["StartDate"]=> string(10) "11/13/2016" ["EndDate"]=> string(10) "11/13/2016" ["StartTime"]=> string(7) " 9:00AM" ["EndTime"]=> string(7) " 5:00PM" ["Location"]=> string(11) "YOGA Class" ["pricing"]=> NULL ["SIZE"]=> int(10) ["REGISTERED_COUNT"]=> int(3) ["WAITING_LIST_COUNT"]=> int(0) ["ProgramClassificationID"]=> string(36) "AFCAB0B2-24FE-427B-8590-812D74749E6A" ["ProgramClassificationName"]=> string(8) "Wellness" ["SemesterID"]=> string(36) "854E61F8-B564-48F6-AFCD-FAEE597AFF0C" ["CourseID"]=> string(36) "84A92D24-12C3-4487-93C1-4DBFAF2D9A3B" ["RegCloseDate"]=> string(19) "Oct 26 2016 12:00AM" } }
```

Comment: Show Your DB structure. What is desired result? I believe You need to `explode` Your values now to do something with them

Comment: added a var_dump of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this within my nested foreach...

```
if ($key=="YOGA") 
{
for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++)
{if(!array_key_exists($value[$i]["offering"], $class))     
$class[$value[$i]["offering"]] = array();
array_push($class[$value[$i]["offering"]], $value[$i]);
}

    foreach($class as $key => $rows):
    //echo something
    echo $key;
        $k = 0;
        foreach ($rows as $row) :
        //echo something
        $k++;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
} else {
// show remaining non-YOGA classes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use this format of array then you can get this solution by following code but this should not be used as it is not optimal solution. you have to use proper data  structure for this, though i have given the code to solve your problem temporary:

```
$yoga = [["category" => "Classes","course" => "Yoga","CourseOfferingId" => "0550AA8D-F437-4578-BD98-95C51D017E62","offering" => "YOGA Session 1","Semester" => "Fall 2016","Days" =>"We", "StartDate" => "10/05/2016", "EndDate" => "10/05/2016", "StartTime" => " 6:00PM", "EndTime" => "10:00PM","Location" => "Off-Site, Quiet Room","pricing" => NULL,"SIZE" =>10,"REGISTERED_COUNT" => 10,"WAITING_LIST_COUNT" => 0,"ProgramClassificationID" => "AFCAB0B2-24FE-427B-8590-812D74749E6A","ProgramClassificationName" =>"Wellnes","SemesterID" => "854E61F8-B564-48F6-AFCD-FAEE597AFF0C","CourseID" => "84A92D24-12C3-4487-93C1-4DBFAF2D9A3B","RegCloseDate" => "Sep 29 2016 12:00AM"],
     ["category" => "Classes","course" => "Yoga","CourseOfferingId" => "0550AA8D-F437-4578-BD98-95C51D017E62","offering" => "YOGA Session 2","Semester" => "Fall 2016","Days" =>"We", "StartDate" => "10/05/2011", "EndDate" => "10/05/2016", "StartTime" => " 6:00PM", "EndTime" => "10:00PM","Location" => "Off-Site, Quiet Room","pricing" => NULL,"SIZE" =>10,"REGISTERED_COUNT" => 10,"WAITING_LIST_COUNT" => 0,"ProgramClassificationID" => "AFCAB0B2-24FE-427B-8590-812D74749E6A","ProgramClassificationName" =>"Wellnes","SemesterID" => "854E61F8-B564-48F6-AFCD-FAEE597AFF0C","CourseID" => "84A92D24-12C3-4487-93C1-4DBFAF2D9A3B","RegCloseDate" => "Sep 29 2016 12:00AM"]];

$sessions = [];
$sessionInformation = [];
foreach($yoga as $key => $yogaElements)
{
   $temporarySessionInfo = [];
   $sessionName = "";
   foreach($yogaElements as $key => $value )
   {
        if($key == "offering"){
           $sessionName = explode(" ",$value)[1]." ".explode(" ",$value)[2];
        }
        if($key == "StartDate"){
           array_push($temporarySessionInfo,"Start Date: ".$value);
        }
        if($key == "EndDate"){
           array_push($temporarySessionInfo,"End Date: ".$value);
        }
        if($key == "StartTime"){
           array_push($temporarySessionInfo,"StartTime: ".$value);
        }
        if($key == "EndTime"){
           array_push($temporarySessionInfo,"End Time: ".$value);
        }   
   }
   if(!array_key_exists($sessionName,$sessions))
   {
       $sessions[$sessionName] = $temporarySessionInfo;
   }
   else
   {
    $sessions[$sessionName] = array_merge($sessions[$sessionName], $temporarySessionInfo);
   }
}

foreach($sessions as $key => $values)
{
   echo $key."<br/>";
   foreach($values as $value)
   {
      echo $value."<br/>";
   }
   echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: added a var_dump of data

Comment: need to re-organize my array with $key [Yoga] to have [Session 1] and [Session 2] are the new keys

Comment: Updated the answer @sloga